# how to find rmi server address on local machine?

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I want to create simple RMI program for client and server to get the date from the server. My server code is compiling but while running I am getting this error: Invalid URL String
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 4: Da
te Server

Code:

```
// IDate.java
import java.rmi.*;
public interface IDate extends Remote{
String getDate() throws RemoteException;
}

// DateImpl.java
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DateImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IDate{
public DateImpl() throws RemoteException{}
public String getDate(){
Date d=new Date();
return(d.toString());
}}

// DateServer.java
import java.rmi.*;
public class DateServer{
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
DateImpl di=new DateImpl();
Naming.rebind("DateServer",di);
System.out.println("Date Server is Ready");
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}}}

// DateClient.java

import java.rmi.*;
public class DateClient{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try{
String url="rmi://127.0.0.1/DateServer";
IDate intf=(IDate)Naming.lookup(url);
System.out.println("The Date On Server is: "+intf.getDate());
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace(); } } }
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception? Add concrete stack trace and the corresponging code please.

Comment: I am running and compiling the code in command prompt.. how to add concrete stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 4: Da te Server
...
Naming.rebind("DateServer",di);
```

Obviously that isn't the real code. In any case it should be

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/DateServer",di);
```